# Cannot set Property 'ProjectId' of Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to edit the details of Projects fecthed from a WebAPI. I can successfully get the list of projects. However when I am trying to edit the list of employees, it keeps showing that 'Cannot set Property 'ProjectId' of Undefined'.

I am new to angular and browsed through multitude of forums but to no avail. I acn't figure out what am I exactly doing wrong.

This is my **project.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { project } from '/home/nineleaps/Desktop/rms/rms/src/app/project.model';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  projectList: Observable<project[]>;
  newproject : project;
  readonly ROOT_URL:any ="http://1fd9e27b.ngrok.io/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProject()
  {
    return this.http.get<project[]>(this.ROOT_URL + '/Projects');
  }

  EditProject(emp: project) {  
    console.log(emp);  
   const params = new HttpParams().set('ProjectId', emp.ProjectId.toString());  
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');  
    var body = {  
      ProjectTitle: emp.ProjectTitle, ProjectDescription: emp.ProjectDescription, ProjectId: emp.ProjectId, StartDate: emp.StartDate
      , EndDate: emp.EndDate
    }  
    return this.http.put<project>(this.ROOT_URL + 'Projects/' + emp.ProjectId, body, { headers, params }) 
    .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));

}
}
```

**Model Class project.model.ts**

```
export class project
{
         ProjectId:number;
         ProjectTitle:string;
         ProjectDescription:string;
         StartDate:Date;
         EndDate:Date;
}
```

**projectlist.component.html**

```
<div class="container">  
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="loadAddnew()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Create New">  
  <hr>  
  <div *ngIf="!dataavailable">  

    <h4> No Project Data is present. PLease click Add new to add Data.</h4>  
  </div>  

  <table class="table table-striped table-dark table-bordered table-hover" *ngIf="dataavailable">
    <caption>Projects</caption>  
    <thead class="thead-light">  
      <tr>  
        <th scope="col">Start Date</th>  
        <th scope="col">Project ID</th>  
        <th scope="col">Project Description</th>  
        <th scope="col">Project Name</th>  
        <th scope="col">End Date</th>  
        <th scope="col" style="align-content: center">Action</th>  
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
      <tr *ngFor="let e of projectList let i = index ">  
        <td scope="col">{{e.StartDate}}</td>  
        <td scope="col">{{e.ProjectId}}</td>  
        <td scope="col">{{e.ProjectDescription}}</td>  
        <td scope="col">{{e.ProjectTitle}}</td>  
        <td scope="col">{{e.EndDate}}</td>  

        <td scope="col">  
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" 
          (click)="loadnewForm(e.ProjectId,e.ProjectTitle,e.ProjectDescription,e.StartDate,e.EndDate)"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaledit">  
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit  
          </button>  
</td>
          <!-- |  
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" (click)="deleteconfirmation(e.id)">  
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete  
          </button>   -->


      </tr>  
    </tbody>  
  </table>  

<!--  COMMENT OUT THIS DIV BEFORE UNCOMMENTING BELOW CODE -->
<!--" -->
  <!-- <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
      <div class="modal-content">  
        <div class="modal-header">  
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>  
          <h4 class="modal-primary">project Add</h4>  
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">  

          <app-project-add #empadd (nameEvent)="RefreshData($event)"></app-project-add>  

        </div>  
        <div class="modal-footer">  
          <button type="button" #closeBtn class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
        </div>  
      </div>  

    </div>  
  </div>  
-->

  <div id="myModaledit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
      <div class="modal-content">  
        <div class="modal-header">  
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>  
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>  
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">  
          <app-projectupdate (nameEvent)="RefreshData($event)" [isReset]="resetForm" #regForm></app-projectupdate>  
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-footer">  
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
        </div>  
      </div>  

    </div>  
  </div>
```

**LOad New Form Function**

```
@ViewChildren('regForm') editcomponent: ProjectUpdateComponent=null;
  loadnewForm(id: number, title: string, description: string, startdate: Date, enddate: Date) {  

    //console.log(typeof(this.editcomponent.objproject.ProjectId));
    try {

    this.editcomponent.objtempproject.ProjectId=id;
    this.editcomponent.objproject.ProjectId = id 
    this.editcomponent.objproject.ProjectTitle= title  
    this.editcomponent.objproject.ProjectDescription = description
    this.editcomponent.objproject.StartDate = startdate
    this.editcomponent.objproject.EndDate = enddate
  }  
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e)
  }

}
}
```

ERROR CODE

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'ProjectId' of undefined
    at ProjectListComponent.push../src/app/project-list/project-list.component.ts.ProjectListComponent.loadnewForm (project-list.component.ts:62)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ProjectListComponent.html:31)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23106)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24176)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23903)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20555)
    at core.js:21002
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
```

Comment: Can you share your projectlist components code?

Comment: sorry my bad got it.

Comment: I know the error is somewhere in LoadNewForm funtion. I have been trying hard but couldn't find the exact reason behind it. When I tried printing out the type of projectid, it shows undefined.

Comment: @AnkitJha Do not assign =null to variable:

Comment: And feel free to provide stackblitz

Comment: How am I supposed to initialize a date variable?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale https://github.com/ankitjhamahi07/Resume-Management

Comment: @AnkitJha Stackblitz are easy to check and reproduce your issue at our end so instead Github provide the minimum code that we can run and check the issue!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an Object of **`project`** class with the variable of `objtempproject` in **`ProjectUpdateComponent`** currently you are just specifying the type of it.

just change below lines of code it will work

> ***ProjectUpdateComponent***

```
  @Input() reset:boolean = false;

  @ViewChildren('regForm') myForm: NgForm;  

  @Input() isReset: boolean = false;  

  objtempproject: project = new project();  // change this line
```

and one more thing is as @Prashant Pimpale said don't assaign **`null`** to to the **`@ViewChild`**

```
@ViewChildren('regForm') editcomponent: ProjectUpdateComponent;
```

Comment: @ViewChildren('regForm') editcomponent: ProjectUpdateComponent;
  objproject:project = new project();